# How to add the value of another field to an HTTParty field using Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, httparty

Is possible to use this: Add password-generated faker content to "**passoword_confirmation**". If so, what is the syntax, try various ways and failed !. Thank's

> "email": Faker::Internet.email,
>       "password": Faker::number(6),
>       "password_confirmation":

```
@@base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
    @@body = 
    {
    "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password": Faker::number(6),
    "password_confirmation":      here I want to receive the password generated from Faker.

     }    
}.to_json
```

Comment: It's not clear what the Capybara tag has to do with this? There is no actual code shown that would use Capybara, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could persist the password by saving it to a variable before entering the `@@body` block.

```
@@base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
fake_password = Faker::number(6)
@@body = 
{
  "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password": fake_password,
    "password_confirmation": fake_password

   }    
}.to_json
```